# r - failing to load imager.so, even though it's there

Tags: r, package, installation

I've already checked a lot of other posts here to see if this is something I can fix easily, but I couldn't find anything (although I am admittedly not very good at searching). I'm trying to install the `imager` package, but keep getting the following error when I call `library(imager)`:

```
Loading required package: imager
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I went to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/imager/libs, and lo and behold there's an executable file called imager.so, presumably the file R says doesn't exist. I've tried removing the package, removing its package and dependencies, and eventually I tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling R. Maybe I didn't nuke my installation correctly? Any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: How did you install it? I'm on macOS (Sierra) and `install.packages('imager")` then `library(imager)` works fine.

Comment: I didn't have Xquartz installed, whoops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imager package depends on a working installation of X11/Xquartz, and hence the error message that imager.so cannot find /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib. Re-installing XQuartz should solve the issue.

Comment: That worked- I must have forgotten to install Xquartz when I wiped my laptop. Thanks!